# Getting Nullpointer exception for XMPPConnection

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, xmpp, smack

I am running openfire server on localhost,
Smack version 4.2.4.Getting exception in getAllContacts() method.
Below is the code for my class XmppConnection which extends class org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener.

```
  public class XmppConnection implements ConnectionListener{
  private  XMPPTCPConnection mConnection;

  public List<Contact> getAllContacts() throws SmackException.NotLoggedInException, InterruptedException, SmackException.NotConnectedException {

    Log.d(TAG,"getAllContats called()");
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    if(XmppConnectService.sConnectionState == ConnectionState.AUTHENTICATED){
        Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(mConnection);  //exception here

            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            Presence presence;

            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                Contact c = new Contact(entry.getJid().toString());
                presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getJid());

                contacts.add(c);
                       }


    return contacts;

}

public XmppConnection( Context context)
{

    mApplicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    String jid = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mApplicationContext)
            .getString("xmpp_jid",null);
    mPassword = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mApplicationContext)
            .getString("xmpp_password",null);

    if( jid != null)
    {
        mUsername = jid.split("@")[0];
        mServiceName = jid.split("@")[1];
    }else
    {
        mUsername ="";
        mServiceName="";
    }
}


public void connect() throws IOException,XMPPException,SmackException
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to server " + mServiceName);

    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(OPENFIRE_HOST);

    HostnameVerifier verifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

            return true;
        }
    };


    DomainBareJid serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom(OPENFIRE_HOST);
    conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
            conf.setXmppDomain(serviceName
            .setHostAddress(addr)
            .setUsernameAndPassword(mUsername,mPassword)
            .setPort(5222)
            .setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
                                      .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)

            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setCompressionEnabled(true);

    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf.build());

    setupUiThreadBroadCastMessageReceiver();

    mConnection.addConnectionListener(this);
    try {

         mConnection.connect();

        mConnection.login(mUsername,mPassword);


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    ReconnectionManager reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
    reconnectionManager.setEnabledPerDefault(true);
    reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection();

    }

}

@Override
public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {
    XmppConnectService.sConnectionState = ConnectionState.CONNECTED;
    Log.w(TAG,"Connected Successfully; id:" + XmppConnectService.sConnectionState);

}

@Override
public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
    XmppConnectService.sConnectionState = ConnectionState.AUTHENTICATED;
    Log.w(TAG,"Authenticated Successfully");
    showContactListActivityWhenAuthenticated();
 }
    }
}
```

Above code is showing this error in logcat :`java.lang.NullPointerException: XMPPConnection must not be null`

I'm calling getAllContacts() from another class as

```
XmppConnection xmpp = new XmppConnection(this);
contacts = xmpp.getAllContacts();
```

getAllContacts() method is called from another activity and is called after authenticated() method.
Since,it is called after authenticated() method, mConnection should have initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a new object for XmppConnection class initializes its variables with null.
Declaring XMPPTCPConnection as **static** works:

```
private static XMPPTCPConnection mConnection;
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is shown on your code you initialize the mConnection variable inside the method connect().
And your method authenticated() does not make any call to the method connect().
Can you please make sure that the method connect() is called even before the call to method authenticated() or within the method

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am sure that authenticated() method is called after connect() method. mConnection.connect() ensures connected() is called followed by authenticated().